# A display indicating the definition of the distance between a point and a line (using only TikZ)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

In the following display, a point `(-4,5)` and a line are drawn.  A dashed line is drawn from `(-4,5)` to the line indicating the distance between them.  I call the intersection between the given line and the dashed line `Q`.  `Q = (0,-1)`.  I draw a dashed line from `(-4,5)` to `Q` and draw a right-angle mark between the given line and the dashed line.  A brace and label for it are drawn. Since the x-axis interferes with the brace, a thicker white brace is first drawn using the option `draw=white` to give the actual brace the appearance of being above the graph.

I would like two modifications.  The y-axis interferes with right-angle mark.  How do I "color" inside the right-angle mark white. Without guessing, how do I properly center the label "d" which indicates the distance between the point and line with respect to the brace?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=5in,clip=false,axis equal image,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-7,xmax=7,
    ymin=-7,ymax=7,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    restrict y to domain=-7:7,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]

\addplot[latex-latex,samples=2,domain=-7:7,blue,name path = line_1] {(2/3)*x - 1} node[anchor=south east,pos=0.9,font=\footnotesize]{$y=\dfrac{2}{3}x - 1$};
\addplot[draw=none,samples=2,domain=-16/3:4,blue,name path = line_2] {(-3/2)*x - 1};
\addplot[mark=*,blue,mark size=1.5pt] coordinates{(-4,5)} node[anchor=west,font=\footnotesize]{$P$};
\draw[name intersections={of= line_1 and line_2, by={Q}}];

%These commands typeset a brace. To give the brace the appearance of being typeset over
%the x-axis, it is typeset in white with a line width of 2pt, which is 10 times the
%thickness of the thickness of the brace that is actually typeset.
\draw[draw=white,line width=4pt,decorate,decoration={brace,raise=5pt,amplitude=5pt,mirror}] (-4,5) -- (Q);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=5pt,amplitude=5pt,mirror}] (-4,5) -- (Q);



%The following commands make the right-angle mark.
\coordinate (U) at ($(Q)!4mm!45:(1.5,0)$);
\draw (U) -- ($(Q)!(U)!(-4,5)$);
\draw (U) -- ($(Q)!(U)!(1.5,0)$);

%The following command draws a dashed line between (-4,5) and Q.
\draw[dashed] (-4,5) -- (Q);


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What seems to be the question here?

Comment: Please always check your code before posting it. As it was it wouldn't compile since you forgot to load `pgfplots`. I've fixed that in my edit.

Comment: Is this meant as a showcase? Remember that this is a question and answer site, you seem to have posted an answer without a clear question. See also http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2943/how-to-share-a-latex-recipe?lq=1

Comment: @Torbjørn T.  I can edit it and at the end say "I have code that gives me the display that I want ... but I am looking for other suggestions."

Comment: @user74973 If that is the case then, yes, please edit so that your question is a question, indicate that you have an answer and then post your answer as an answer. That saves people a lot of time trying to figure out what is going on: it is clear and makes it possible to find things.

Comment: @cfr   I already did this - hours ago.

Comment: So that isn't the case, after all. That's fine. My response was formulated as a conditional. The antecedent fails, so the consequent is irrelevant.

Comment: @cfr  I agree.  Percusse offered code that is different from mine for centering the "d" with respect to the brace.  I'm not sure that I prefer it, but it is nice to have alternatives.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You can basically do everything as you go along the path with naming coordinates and continuing by referring to those. There is no need for intersections for this example.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=5in,clip=false,axis equal image,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-7,xmax=7,
    ymin=-7,ymax=7,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    restrict y to domain=-7:7,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]

\addplot[latex-latex,samples=2,domain=-7:7,blue] {(2/3)*x - 1} 
    coordinate [pos=0] (s) 
    coordinate (e)
    node[anchor=south east,pos=0.9,font=\footnotesize]{$y=\dfrac{2}{3}x - 1$};

\draw[dashed,
    decoration={brace,raise=5pt,amplitude=5pt},
    postaction={draw,solid,decorate}] 
    ($(s)!0.5!(e)$) coordinate (m) --($($(s)!0.5!(e)$)!0.8!90:(e)$)
     node[circle,inner sep=2pt,fill=blue,label={[blue,font=\footnotesize]45:$P$}] (p){}
    ($($(m)!0.5!(p)$)!10pt!90:(p)$) node[anchor=east] {$d$};

\draw[fill=white] ($(m)!3mm!(e)$) coordinate (U) 
     -- ($(U)!3mm!90:(e)$) -- ($(m)!3mm!(p)$) -- (m) -- cycle;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]